# c# Insert more than 32767 rows IBM400

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange

Trying to insert more than 32767 rows i get errors... How I can increase this limit?

Thanks for your time!

SQL0221 Numero di righe  non valido.

(SQL0221 Rows Numbers non valid.)

Rows numbers is 104328 (param.Count)

> ((IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Exception) ex) .MessageDetails: 
>   Cause. . . : FETCH instruction blocked, INSERT blocked or SET RESULT SETS invalid. The number of lines specified is not between 0 and 32767 or is larger than the host's host size. The number of rows specified is and the size of the array. If this is a FETCH instruction, the cursor name is ?? lÜ * N. 
> Fix.: make sure that the number of lines is between 0 and 32767 and that it is less than or equal to the size of the array or increase the size of the array.

```
using (iDB2Connection cnn = new iDB2Connection(Db2ConStr))
        {
            iDB2Transaction trans = null;`enter code here`
            iDB2Command cmd = null;
            try
            {
                //cnn = new iDB2Connection(Db2ConStr);
                cmd = new iDB2Command
                {
                    Connection = cnn,
                    CommandText = sInsertSql
                };
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.DeriveParameters();
                // Insert 10 rows of data at once
                for (int i = 0; i < param.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Here, you set your parameters for a single row
                    cmd.Parameters["@SETTORE_GESTIONALE"].Value = param[i].SETTORE_GESTIONALE;
                    cmd.Parameters["@RAPPORTO_GESTIONALE"].Value = param[i].RAPPORTO_GESTIONALE ;
                    cmd.Parameters["@DATA_RIFERIMENTO"].Value = param[i].DATA_RIFERIMENTO    ;
                    cmd.Parameters["@FLAG_AFFIDATO_CASSA"].Value = param[i].FLAG_AFFIDATO_CASSA;
                    cmd.Parameters["@FLAG_AFFIDATO_SBF"].Value = param[i].FLAG_AFFIDATO_SBF  ;
                    cmd.AddBatch();
                }



                trans = cnn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
                int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trans.Rollback();
                //trans.Commit();
                cnn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                cnn.Close();
                Log.TraceOnFilesystem(ex);
                Log.TraceOnFilesystem(sInsertSql);
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: What does the SQL look like? I am guessing that you are doing an insert, and that you have an array containing the data to insert. But where is the data coming from? If you could insert from a select statement, then you can insert more at a time. It is only when you are inserting from a host structure that you have this limitation.

Comment: The data in this transaction are coming from a List<param> param, I can't use select statement because the data are stored in sqlserver. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message, there is a row limit on blocked statements. Those statements are `INSERT`, `FETCH`, and `SET RESULT SETS`. The limit is the smaller of 32,767 or the number of elements in your host array. If you are inserting rows from a host array, then the most you can insert in a single shot is 32,767 (as long as your array can handle it). If you need to insert 100,000 rows, you will have to split it up. The only place I can find this documented is in the message itself https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzala/rzalaml.htm.

Comment: Thanks! At least we've a complete answer. By the way I've splitted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the z/OS insert has a limitation of 32767 rows on a blocked insert.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_insert.html

However, the corresponding documentation for IBM i does not state the same limitation.  It is possible that it exists and just isn't documented though.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzbackup.htm

This limit may also depend on the version of the OS that your IBM i system is running on.

Update: Per jmarkmurphy's answer, it looks like there is a limitation on IBM i as well.

Comment: This is DB2 on IBM i not mainframe, but there is typically a configurable limitation on the size of a table (physical file) - see my answer just posted.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have no idea what you're trying to do. I don't know what IBM400 is or how to use it, but I guess the below is maybe a solution?

```
try
{
  //cnn = new iDB2Connection(Db2ConStr);
  cmd = new iDB2Command
  {
    Connection = cnn,
    CommandText = sInsertSql
  };
  cnn.Open();
  cmd.DeriveParameters();

  int index;
  while(index < parms.Count)
  {
      cmd.DeriveParameters();
      // Insert 10 rows of data at once

      // Here, you set your parameters for a single row
      cmd.Parameters["@SETTORE_GESTIONALE"].Value = param[i].SETTORE_GESTIONALE;
      cmd.Parameters["@RAPPORTO_GESTIONALE"].Value = param[i].RAPPORTO_GESTIONALE ;
      cmd.Parameters["@DATA_RIFERIMENTO"].Value = param[i].DATA_RIFERIMENTO    ;
      cmd.Parameters["@FLAG_AFFIDATO_CASSA"].Value = param[i].FLAG_AFFIDATO_CASSA;
      cmd.Parameters["@FLAG_AFFIDATO_SBF"].Value = param[i].FLAG_AFFIDATO_SBF  ;
      cmd.AddBatch();



      if(index % 32767 == 0 || index == params.Count() - 1)
      {
          trans = cnn.BeginTransaction();
          cmd.Transaction = trans;
          int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          trans.Rollback();
          cmd = new iDB2Command
          {
             Connection = cnn,
             CommandText = sInsertSql
          };
      }

      index++;
  }
```

I don't know where you're getting the exception, so I guessed that the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" was the problem cause.

Maybe you're forced to add them ALL and send the ALL at once, in which case my solution won't work.

However, if not, hopefully you can implement the logic that I've used on trying to dodge the max limit size

Comment: "Maybe you're forced to add them ALL and send the ALL at once, in which case my solution won't work."

Exactly... I'm trying insert 100 thousand records at once. I can't?

Comment: Well, you can if you split them up. I assume the max value is there for a reason.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot. I've already split, but I prefer at once, but if not possible, that's right

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe there is a way to do as you ask.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me as if you may be coming up against the max records setting on the table you're inserting into; you'll need to increase this (CHGPF command). If that is the case there will be a relevant message in the history log (DSPLOG).

Comment: I'll try your solution advice... Thanks!

Comment: I've tried, but doens't work... :(
Should be some stuff in IBM for .NET drivers I think

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.